# C# XmlReader Colon Issues (Namespace)

Tags: c#, feed, atom-feed

I have a strange problem with the XMLReader class. I get atom feed from a URL, and some elements of the xml tree are named like these:

```
<element:title>Hello World!</element:title>
<element:text>This is just an example</element:text>
<element:id>1</element:id>
```

Im using

```
[XmlElement("element:id")]
```

but this is not working. When I look through the code I see that the reader parse this as

```
element_x003A_id
```

but if I use

```
[XmlElement("element_x003A_id)]
```

I get nothing. I tried fiddling with the Xml encoding, but the property is read-only. How can I escape this, so I can get the content of the elements (if the element does not have semicolon it works just fine)?

Comment: See this link: [Namespaces in XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302166.aspx)

Comment: btw, `:` is a colon; a semi-colon is `;`

Comment: Marc you're right, sleep deprivation is the silent killer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`element` is a namespace alias. Somewhere, you have (at the top of the file, usually)

```
<foo ... xmlns:element="http://something/blah/blog">
```

the "http://something/blah/blog" is important. Basically, you need:

```
[XmlElement("id", Namespace="http://something/blah/blog")]
public int Id {get;set;}
```

Or since it is going to be used repeatedly:

```
const string MyNamespace = "http://something/blah/blog";
//...
[XmlElement("id", Namespace=MyNamespace)]
public int Id {get;set;}
```

Comment: Thank you, im embarrassed to have missed something so fundamental.

Comment: @Anonymous just for the record, the alias `element` is not significant except to the reader; a different file could **perfectly legally** use `xmlsn:evil=...` and `<evil:id>` - and the data would be **identical**. That is why `[XmlElement(...)]` knows about the *namespace*, but doesn't need to know about the *alias*. In fact, you don't even need an alias; it could be `<id xmlns="...">` and it would still be exactly the same data.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, adding Namespace works perfect.